# How to capture Image automatically in Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I can open the camera (both front and back) but I can only take picture using camera button! I want to capture the image automatically with some time delay or count down.

I used this to open camera

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Camera2Activity.class)
.putExtra("prevent_camera", CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FRONT_CAMERA);
```

Camera2Activity:

```
public class Camera2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance(getIntent().getIntExtra("prevent_camera",0)))
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the work is done in Camera2Activity.class. You should post code for that as well.

Comment: Camera2Activity shows  Camera2BasicFragment. You can add delay there.

Comment: But the fragment is not taking picture automatically, its is opening with a camera button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559862/how-to-capture-image-without-user-knowledge-using-surface-view