# Take a picture without opening the Camera application

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I currently have an application with a button that takes a photo. However, when I click the button the default camera application opens, then you manually have to take a photo. How do I get the camera application to not open and just take a picture automatically and save it just by pressing the button in my application? I would like to press the button that I created and it takes a photo and saves it automatically.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //for taking photos
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    String currentPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

    }

//button to start image capturing process
    public void startImageCapture(View view){

        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        galleryAddPic();

    }

//method for taking a photo
    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //Ensure that there is a camera activity to handle the intent
        if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            //create the file where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try{
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.i("ERROR","Error in trying to create file for image");
            }
            //continue only if the file was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null){
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.MyProject.provider",photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }

        }
    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        //Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, //prefix
                ".jpg", //suffix
                storageDir //directory
        );

        //Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void galleryAddPic(){
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use MediaCodec and MediaRecorder for this, defining camera output as your input surface, instead of sending an intent to camera

Comment: Would that be using the Camera2 API?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559862/how-to-capture-image-without-user-knowledge-using-surface-view

Comment: @blackapps I just tried that solution but much of the code base has been depreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the easiest solution is using camera view (your own wrapper of Camera2 API or existing [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView)) inside your application and making it invisible or placing some view above it, if you want to hide it.
CameraView API is simple ([CameraView Getting Started](https://natario1.github.io/CameraView/about/getting-started.html)): just add view into layout, set LifecycleOwner, set callback on taking picture and call *camera.takePicture()*, when you need to take picture.

Comment: I am starting to try CameraView  inside of my application. What do you set as the callback parameter?

Comment: @westerie `camera.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(PictureResult result) {
        // A Picture was taken!
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onVideoTaken(VideoResult result) {
        // A Video was taken!
    }
    
    // And much more
})`

Comment: All examples you can see [here](https://natario1.github.io/CameraView/about/getting-started.html). Callback returns PictureResult , from which you can take bitmap and save it.